# Verify values in combo box exist or don't exist?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I verify all the items listed in a combo box? Like for example I want to check if a combo box have "item1" "item2" "item3". How do I output all options out and check?

Here's how to excess the combobox:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=boxname]')[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the store of your box and interrogate it. For example:

```
var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=boxname]')[0].getStore();
console.log(store.getById('item1'));
```

If `item1` is not there the result will be `null`.

UPDATE:

> Based on conditions lets say, I want to be able to validate the combo
>   box that it only has "item1" and "item2", not any more or any less.

Given that say the variable `target` contains what you want in your combo, you can verify your combo this way:

```
var target = ['item1', 'item2'],
    combo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=boxname]')[0],
    check = function(combo, target) {
        var store = combo.getStore();
        if (target.length !== store.getTotalCount()) {
            return false;
        }
        var result = true;
        store.each(function(item){
            if (!Ext.Array.contains(target, item.getId())) {
                result = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
console.log(check(combo, target));
```

The method `check` will return `true` if the combo contains what you want, or `false` otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to output all the values on a given combo box?

Comment: Sure there is. `store.each(function(item){console.log(item.getId());})` or `store.each(function(item){console.log(item.get(valueField));})`.

Comment: there is no need to output all the values in the combobox or put them into an array and then validate them - see my answer

Comment: But I do want to validate the combo box to see if it has what i need or what i don't need. Based on conditions lets say, I want to be able to validate the combo box that it only has "item1" and "item2", not any more or any less.

Comment: could i use that check for a  target string variable that is comma separated such as: string myString = "1,2,3,4,5"; var target = [myString].....

Comment: Sure, just explode your string into array: `target.split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=boxname]')[0].getStore();

store.each(function(record){
    var name = rec.get('name');// instead of name use the attribute you want to use for the validation
    if(name === 'code4jhon'){
         console.log('this dudes name is code4jhon')
     }

});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each